# WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE equivalent in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, border

How to set a Silverlight control border to something like CSS

```
border:2px ThreeDFace inset;
```

(or WinAPI WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE)?

Comment: Do you mean something like `<Border BorderThickness="0,0,2,2" BorderBrush="Gray" Padding="10"><TextBlock Text="Blah Blah Blah"/></Border>` ?

Comment: Is there a way to do so with system colors and with other color for left and top border, or nesting two <Border>s with inline color definitions is the only solution?

Comment: Ya about that, it may not be the only solution, but it's the only one I know off the top of my head.